# The 6 character edit threshhold and replacing links

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, hyperlinks, character-limit

Say you come across an old post and linked in it is this URL:

> https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/shelve.html

Updating the URL changes only three characters and doesn't surpass the edit threshold:

> https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shelve.html

It's a fairly minor edit, but seeing as the post in question had 30k views, surely it's reasonable to save everyone a couple of seconds for minor edits like this?

I imagine the most efficient workaround to the 6 character rule is to parse URLs as one block, so edits to the URL count for more characters.

Comment: Editing an old post, be it a question or an answer, is a sensitive issue. If the link is changed/updated you risk nullifying answers that responded to the original link, which is not good. Changing the url or updating a link could also affect the author's answer perhaps they are quoting directly from the original page and now anyone visiting the new site might be confused to see that the citation is not mentioned or is significantly different to the answer posted.

Comment: If the newer url contains no new information, but the site is more pleasing and easier to read, I suppose the edit is acceptable, in which case add the expression: "Updated", and include the date, these minor changes will easily overcome  the six character limit.

Comment: The Python 2.x documentation ***is not broken*** and will stick around, effectively forever. Even most 1.x documentation is still available (e.g. the [Python 1.4 docs are still online](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/), and have been for almost 1/4 of a century). Please don’t go on an editing spree, there is absolutely nothing wrong with those links.

Comment: However, **if** it makes sense for a link to take you to the most recent version of a Python documentation page, then please remove the version number altogether. E.g. use https://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html, this currently takes you to https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html which you may note is the generic 3.x link. Those links won’t then need updating again when [Python 3.9 is released this fall](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0596/#schedule) nor if there is ever going to be a Python 4.x series. *Sometimes* you need the major.minor specifi version, but that’s rare.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Please, for the love of Guido van Rossum, Tim Peters and Jeff Atwood, don’t put “updated” or “edited” in posts. There is no need, it is just noise, we have the post history link for that.

Comment: @Martijn adding the date within the post makes it immediately noticeable. Not every visitor is a registered user, not every user intuitively knows about the edit history. Adding that *small* piece of information can be a service, there's no need to call upon the "creators" of Python (had to look them up), and Stack Exchange, relax, there is no damage. To be clear my comment refers to the updating of any link on any SE site, I leave answers concerning Python to the experts

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: If the information is necessary, it should not take this form. The post should be as if it was written today.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: those visitors then **don't care that the post was edited in the past**. That's not the information they come looking for, that's then just noise. The majority of anonymous visitors come to the post for the first time, anyway.

Answer (score 8):

You often find there's more context - and python 2.x and 3.x are *substantially* different - these might not be desirable or simple edits. Considering the reputation requirements for comments are lower than that for edits, I suspect dropping a comment might be a great workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, it isn't necessary to edit a post only to update a link like this; when you visit the 2.7 Python docs, you can easily switch to the version you're using (which may be older or newer than 3.8). I do agree that it's nice to do it *if you edit the post for another substantial reason*.

If an edit like this is really necessary (e.g. because the current link doesn't work anymore), and there's absolutely nothing else you can improve in the post, there are some workarounds to get to the 6 character limit. If a post is linked like this:

```
[link to documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/shelve.html)
```

you can move the link to the end of the post:

```
[link to documentation][1]

... other text

[1]: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shelve.html
```

If it is already referenced this way, I guess you could change the reference number; `[shelve]` works just as well as `[1]` in this regard.

Comment: Moving around the link is a fair workaround which I haven't considered, thanks!

Comment: Other solutions include adding a comment, for example `<!-- broken link fixed -->`